# Generate pixel density map (heatmap) from image with numpy array manipulation

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

The specific problem I try to solve is:
I have a binary image [binary map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V1ED.png) that I want to generate a heatmap (density map) for, my idea is to get the 2D array of this image, let say it is 12x12

```
a = np.random.randint(20, size=(12, 12));
```

index and process it with a fixed-size submatrix (let say 3x3), so for every submatrix, a pixel percentage value will be calculated (nonzero pixels/total pixel).

```
submatrix = a[0:3, 0:3]
pixel_density = np.count_nonzero(submatrix) / submatrix.size
```

At the end, all the percentage values will made up a new 2D array (a smaller, 4x4 density array) that represent the density estimation of the original image. Lower resolution is fine because the data it will be compared to has a lower resolution as well.

I am not sure how to do that through numpy, especially for the indexing part. Also if there is a better way for generating heatmap like that, please let me know as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to convert the binary  image to grayscale and resize it to 12x12?

Comment: @AlexAlex Hello Alex, the original image is a probability map (gray scale, generated through weka segmentation), however, there are some lower intensity value there that I don't want to take them into account because those are not positivity, and thus I threshold it to binary. Also the 12x12 just for the sake of discussion, the actual resolution is 1000+ x 6000+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a [2-D convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)? Basically this will sweep through the `a` matrix with the `b` matrix, which is just 1s below. So it will do the summation you were looking for. This [link](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) has a visual demo of convolution near the bottom.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

a = np.random.randint(2, size=(12, 12))
b = np.ones((4,4))
signal.convolve2d(a,b, 'valid') / b.sum()
```

Comment: Sounds like a solid idea, is it possible to set the stride size in this function? or is it by default going to apply on every pixel on the image? Thanks again!